# Python to append download link to list of files in Dropbox API

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary, dropbox

I'm trying to pull a list of dictionaries from Dropbox API for some images and to be represented as follows;

```
[{name: 'XYZ', url: 'THIS IS A URL'}]
```

I've use the following which generates a list of file names and path's just fine.

```
path = ''
files_list = []

def dropbox_list_files(path):

    dbx = dropbox_connect()

    try:
        files = dbx.files_list_folder(path).entries
        for file in files:
            if isinstance(file, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):
                metadata = {
                    'name': file.name,
                    'path_lower': file.path_lower,
                    }
                files_list.append(metadata)
```

But I'm stuck on now creating the sharable links, aswell as then appending these to each of the relevant files in a list.

In the Dropbox API documentation they have the 'sharing_create_shared_link_with_settings' function which looks like it can do this, but requires a file path, which I am not sure if this is just a single path, or how I could A) pass in an iterable of paths for all the files in sequence, and then B) how would I append these together for the purpose explained above?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the files_list populated, loop through and pass the file path to the sharing_create_shared_link method. To do that, you would add something like this to your script to print a list of links..

```
for file in files_list:
    try:
        link = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(file['path_lower'])
        print(link.url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Assuming you are using the Dropbox SDK, you will want to ensure you have appropriate scopes set (e.g. sharing.write) otherwise will you encounter a permission error.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. This has worked in generating the urls. Two questions A) how would I combine my two lists so that the correct URL is concatanated to the correct dictionary key ('name'). And secondly, B) the run time is quite slow currently (using the above two for loops both with blank list appends. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: You can refactor your code to A) print the name + shared url concatenated and B) handle the link generation within the same loop to improve performance. Something like this.. https://gist.github.com/tylerjhill/3ba605fc193b4d027c44862752a18355

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler. That did the job. The only thing with it is that it is quite slow when working over a large amount of images. For example 200 is taking over a minute. Any idea how to make this code more efficient?

Comment: Awesome, glad that worked. Technically speaking the reference code is efficient, but your objective is generate all the links faster. You can use the multiprocess module to open multiple threads to shorten the execution time of the script. Check the gist I shared - updated the code and that cut the total time in half.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much Tyler. Yeah that has helped alot, and reduced the run time with what I'm working on by 75%! Also given me something new to learn about. Thank you. 

I was looking into this yesterday and looks like this is a known issue with the 'create shared link' function of DBX API, which appears to be inherently slow: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Creating-and-getting-shared-links-through-the-API-is-way-too/td-p/423293

Do you have a Patreon or 'buy me a coffee' account setup. Would love to tip you for your efforts :)

Comment: Excellent, happy the multithreading update helped boost the script performance. That DBX method does seem to be poor performing, glad they are aware. Very kind of you to offer a coffee, have a Patreon page here: https://www.patreon.com/tyler_hill many thanks!